# Meaning of "before my god"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Please, consider the following statements of the book Hamlet:

> BARNARDO
>   “How now, Horatio? You tremble and look pale.
>   Is not this something more than fantasy?
>   What think you on ’t?
>   HORATIO
>   **Before my God**, I might not this believe
>   Without the sensible and true avouch
>   Of mine own eyes.”

What does the term before my god mean? Is the meaning of it no different from the phrase as god is my witness?

Comment: Yes. It's the same as [*I swear before God (that the evidence I shall give, etc., etc.)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+swear+before+god%22)

Answer (score 2):

*As God as my witness* is typically used with resolutions, threats, or promises - e.g. things you will do in the future.

*Before my God, X* is like saying "X would/wouldn't happen even if you were before God" - which is better if X is someone believing that something is true.

The underlying meaning is the same, that you are really serious about X.